# child_of not working while searching

Tags: functions, customization, filters, search, hacks

I'm trying to limit search to a parent page and its own child pages.

I've changed searchform.php adding this code:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php
    global $post;
    $ancestors2 = $post->ancestors;
    if ($ancestors2) {
        echo end($ancestors2);
    } else {
        echo $post->ID;
    } ?>" name="childof" />
```

Also I've add a function to my theme's functions.php:

```
function SearchFilter($query) {
if (is_search() && !empty($_GET['s']) && !empty($_GET['childof'])) {
    $parent_page_id = intval($_GET['childof']);
    $query->set('child_of', $parent_page_id );
}
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
```

I've tested variables with `var_dump($query)` and it returned:

```
["child_of"]=>
    int(104)
```

But, I still can see search results from other pages and not only from parent page (or its child pages).

Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WP_Query` does not have `child_of` argument.

You might be looking for `post_parent` or `post_parent__in`, see [Post & Page Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).